# Dynamically update QML GUI values

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have bunch of data that has to be displayed continuously on the GUI. I can actually achieve it by setting timer and assigning the new values to the displayed values but I do not want to do in that way. Is there any solution or practical way to do that?

Comment: have you tried to use "states" ?

Comment: could you please be more specific about states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options to achieve that:

1. All your data have a `Q_PROPERTY`. That means create a get function and a signal
2. If you want to show them under a list or a treeview, I suggest you gather all the data up, under a `QAbstractListModel`.
   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html

Then implementing the function data, index, ecc., you will have everything already done for the UI

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Q_Property? Notify Signal may work for your situation.
You can find the documentation from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html).

Comment: `Q_PROPERTY` is the only correct answer and correct way for solving the issue. Especially for QML interfaces. Set it up via C++ and emit property change when you set new value to this property.

Answer (score 0):

First, I defined the property and added the notifier called ***payloadChanged*** to the signals of my class.

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<qreal> PayloadList READ getPayloadList NOTIFY payloadChanged)
```

Secondly,

```
    qmlRegisterType<<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>>("sample1.sample2", 1, 0, "<QML_ITEM_NAME>");
```

Finally

```
QML_ITEM_NAME{
    console.log("PROPERTY")
}
```

When I applied these steps my data is automatically updated without any timer stuff.